# ValidationError: "column" is not allowed to be empty on null column

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

When trying to set `passwordResetToken` to `null` I get not allowed to be empty errors. If I manually run the query against the db, no trouble.

The full code to update user is as follows:

```js
let user = await this.usersRepository.getById(userId);
// ...
const userData = {
    encryptedPassword: await bcrypt.hash(
        newPasswd,
        Number(process.env.BCRYPT_ROUNDS)
    ),
    passwordResetToken: null,
    passwordResetExpires: null
};

user = await this.usersRepository.update(user.id, userData);
```

I have a model defined as such

```js
const User = sequelize.define(
'user',
{
    forename: DataTypes.STRING,
    surname: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    encryptedPassword: DataTypes.STRING,
    passwordResetToken: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: false
        }
    },
    passwordResetExpires: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null,
        validate: {
            isDate: true
        }
    }
},
{
    classMethods: {
        associate() {
            // associations can be defined here
        }
    }
}
);
```

As you can see `allowNull` is true, `defaultValue` is null and `validate:  notEmpty` set to false. What am I missing?

Using sequelize v4.42.0

Dialect 'mysql'

Comment: try remove validate: {
            notEmpty: false
        }

Comment: Same result. I've also noticed setting notEmpty msg does not change returned message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually caused by another part of my validation by npm module [structure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/structure).

I had to set `empty` to true in my schema like this:

```
  passwordResetToken: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    empty: true
  },
```